# Why doesn't my code in "test.py" display anything when I "import test"?

Tags: python

I have this code in a file called `test.py`:

```
person = {'name': 'Jemm', 'age': '23'}
sentence = 'My name is ' + person['name'] + 'and i am' + person['age'] + 'years old.'

print(sentence)
```

When I try `import test`, I don't get any output. Why?

Comment: From a fresh interpreter? Have you checked that `print(test.__file__)` is printing your file + 'c'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import test
>>> print(test)
<module 'test' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/test/__init__.py'>
```

There is a `test` module in Python itself. Be sure you are running your module. You must be in the same directory as your file `test.py` to import your file instead of the Python one.

Update: Python uses a search path list mechanism for finding modules when importing. The "current working directory" is usually at the first place in this list (the empty string). See [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

You can add your own path(s) into `PYTHONPATH` (in shell/command line) or `sys.path` (in Python).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you didn't save the file after you did all the code in `test.py`, what happens if save it then run `import test` somewhere else, that's what i think

Also as Messa said, "There is a test module in Python itself. Be sure you are running your module. You must be in the same directory as your file test.py to import your file instead of the Python one." that's also useful information, have to be same directory as `test.py` (your file)

If you're not in the same directory, do:

```
__import__('whole filepath')
```

For it.